# How to write a loop that I can store different sets in different container:

Tags: python-2.7

I have a big dic that contains different miRNA and their target genes.
I use dic.values to pop out their target genes.
Because I want to calculate their intersection of target genes (it's also called shared targets),using the set.().
Now I have a problem that is:
How to write a loop that I can store different sets in different container:

I want to modify this script:

```
a1 = set(d1.values()[0])
a2 = set(d1.values()[1])
a3 = set(d1.values()[2])
```

Please give me a hand.T

Answer (score 0):

If you only need an intersection of all values:

```
set.intersection(*d1.values())
```

Comment: I need to use a formula like set1 & set2, so I have to store them in different containers? Can you help me? Or there are other ways to find the intersection of two sets in one container?

Comment: I have to caculate the shared targets A by B or B by C,not all of them.